# Next parameter in url not showing but is printing correctly in django

Tags: python, django

This is my signup view:

```
def signup(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next', '')
    print(next)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            first_name=request.POST['first_name']
            email=request.POST['email']
            password=request.POST['password']
            cpassword=request.POST['cpassword']
            signup_uri = f'/signup?next={next}'

            if password==cpassword:
                if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    messages.info(request,'Email already in use')
                    return redirect(signup_uri)
                elif User.objects.filter(mobile=mobile).exists():
                    messages.info(request,'Mobile Number already in use')
                    return redirect(signup_uri)
                else:
                    user=User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name,email=email,password=password)
                    user.save();
                    return redirect(f'/login?next={next}')
            else:
                messages.info(request,'Passwords not matching')
                return redirect('signup_uri')
        
        else:
            return render(request,'signup.html')
```

The problem I am facing is that when I am printing next under `def signup` it is printing it correctly but when it has to redirect it redirects without showing anything as next in url. That is `signup_uri = f'/signup?next={next}'` and `return redirect(f'/login?next={next}')` are showing the {next} as empty.What could be the reason?Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the definition of the `signup` method, you are only retrieving the value of the `next` parameter only for the `GET` request. But when you are trying for a `POST` request, you do not retrieve the value of the `next` parameter. For this reason, the value of the `next` variable is set to `""` and hence, the value of the `signup_uri` variable is being set as `"/signup?next="` as well as for the login redirecting url (`"/login?next="`) too. In order to get rid of this problem, your code should be similar to as follows.

```
def signup(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next', '')
    print(next)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            first_name = request.POST['first_name']
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']
            cpassword = request.POST['cpassword']
            next = request.POST.get("next", "")
            signup_uri = f'/signup?next={next}'

            if password == cpassword:
                if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    messages.info(request,'Email already in use')
                    return redirect(signup_uri)
                elif User.objects.filter(mobile=mobile).exists():
                    messages.info(request,'Mobile Number already in use')
                    return redirect(signup_uri)
                else:
                    user = User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name, email=email, password=password)
                    user.save();
                    return redirect(f'/login?next={next}')
            else:
                messages.info(request, 'Passwords not matching')
                return redirect('signup_uri')
    
        else:
            return render(request, 'signup.html')
```

Comment: Is next = request.POST.get("next", "") the only change that you made. If yes then it is still giving me the same problem

Comment: Are you sending any value for the `next` parameter in the `POST` request from the front-end app? Even if you were not sending any value, without the fix done by me the problem would have been unresolved.

Comment: I am passing this in my signup.html `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">` in the form.

Comment: Debug in the template to check if the value of the `{{ next }}` parameter for the `POST` request is set or not.

Comment: Instead of `next=request.POST.get('next','')` I did `next=request.POST['next']` and in template I changed it to `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}">` and now it seems to be working. Will I get any problem in doinf this way

Comment: If the `request.GET.next` passes the exact value as you are expecting, then it is fine. Please don't forget to upvote the answer if it helps you resolve your problem. TIA.